# Unusual sunspot_rails behaviour with some keywords not matching

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot-rails

I have found a very strange bug using Sunspot Rails, with some keywords being ignored/not matching.

If you go here:

http://www.ycn.org/showcase/portfolios

and search for "Owen" you will return two records.

http://www.ycn.org/showcase/portfolios?utf8=%E2%9C%93&keywords=owen

However if you type in "Davey", you will not return any matches, when though this should match "Owen Davey". "Owen Davey" is contained in the same field.

Why should this be?

In my model:

```
  searchable do
text :name, :boost => 2.0
text :url
text :description
boolean :is_published
integer :city_id, :references => City
text :city_name, :more_like_this => true do |portfolio|
  portfolio.city.name if portfolio.city.present?
end
integer :country_id, :references => Country do |portfolio|
  portfolio.city.country.id if portfolio.city.present? && portfolio.city.country.present?
end
text :country_name, :more_like_this => true do |portfolio|
  portfolio.country.name if portfolio.city.present? && portfolio.city.country.present?
end
integer :discipline_ids, :references => Discipline, :multiple => true
text :discipline_names, :more_like_this => true do |portfolio|
  portfolio.disciplines.map { |discipline| discipline.name }
end
integer :tag_ids, :references => Tag, :multiple => true
text :tag_names, :more_like_this => true do |portfolio|
  portfolio.tags.map { |tag| tag.name }
end
integer :portfolio_edit_ids, :references => PortfolioEdit, :multiple => true
text :portfolio_edit_titles, :more_like_this => true do |portfolio|
  portfolio.portfolio_edits.map { |edit| edit.title }
end
string :sort_name do
  name.downcase
end
```

end

in my controller:

```
search = Sunspot.search(Portfolio) do |query|

query.keywords params[:keywords], :fields => [:name, :url, :description] if params[:keywords].present?

end
```

My schema.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<schema name="sunspot" version="1.0">
  <types>

    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="rand" class="solr.RandomSortField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
      <analyzer type="index">
          <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
        </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="DoubleMetaphone" inject="true"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.DateField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="sdouble" class="solr.SortableDoubleField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="sfloat" class="solr.SortableFloatField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="sint" class="solr.SortableIntField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="slong" class="solr.SortableLongField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true"/>
  </types>
  <fields>

    <!-- *** This field is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <field name="id" stored="true" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This field is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <field name="type" stored="false" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This field is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <field name="class_name" stored="false" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This field is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <field name="text" stored="false" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This field is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <field name="lat" stored="true" type="tdouble" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This field is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <field name="lng" stored="true" type="tdouble" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="random_*" stored="false" type="rand" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="_local*" stored="false" type="tdouble" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_text" stored="false" type="text" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_texts" stored="true" type="text" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_b" stored="false" type="boolean" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_bm" stored="false" type="boolean" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_bs" stored="true" type="boolean" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_bms" stored="true" type="boolean" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_d" stored="false" type="date" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_dm" stored="false" type="date" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ds" stored="true" type="date" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_dms" stored="true" type="date" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_e" stored="false" type="sdouble" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_em" stored="false" type="sdouble" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_es" stored="true" type="sdouble" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ems" stored="true" type="sdouble" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_f" stored="false" type="sfloat" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_fm" stored="false" type="sfloat" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_fs" stored="true" type="sfloat" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_fms" stored="true" type="sfloat" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_i" stored="false" type="sint" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_im" stored="false" type="sint" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_is" stored="true" type="sint" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ims" stored="true" type="sint" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_l" stored="false" type="slong" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_lm" stored="false" type="slong" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ls" stored="true" type="slong" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_lms" stored="true" type="slong" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_s" stored="false" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_sm" stored="false" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ss" stored="true" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_sms" stored="true" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_it" stored="false" type="tint" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_itm" stored="false" type="tint" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_its" stored="true" type="tint" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_itms" stored="true" type="tint" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ft" stored="false" type="tfloat" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ftm" stored="false" type="tfloat" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_fts" stored="true" type="tfloat" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ftms" stored="true" type="tfloat" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_dt" stored="false" type="tdate" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_dtm" stored="false" type="tdate" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_dts" stored="true" type="tdate" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_dtms" stored="true" type="tdate" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_textv" stored="false" termVectors="true" type="text" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_textsv" stored="true" termVectors="true" type="text" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_et" stored="false" termVectors="true" type="tdouble" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_etm" stored="false" termVectors="true" type="tdouble" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ets" stored="true" termVectors="true" type="tdouble" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_etms" stored="true" termVectors="true" type="tdouble" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
  </fields>

  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
  <!-- field for the QueryParser to use when an explicit fieldname is absent -->
  <defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
  <!-- SolrQueryParser configuration: defaultOperator="AND|OR" -->
  <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>

</schema>
```

Comment: Show your solr/conf/schema.xml and model|controller

Comment: @xdsemx sorry - just have

Answer (score 1):

Mayby try my schema.xml?

https://gist.github.com/xdsemx/5038249

I had a similar problem

Comment: Thanks but the same problem persists with that schema, after reindexing. This is super strange!

Comment: Yep it was helpfull )